# Using @media print for input types (also for IE)

Tags: javascript, html, pdf

I'm working on a html to **pdf converter**. I've got documents which the users can fill, save and download as **PDF** file.

I've got a problem, because when I get ID of div and print it, the fields are empty, so I am printing whole window, just like this:

```
$scope.printer = function(){
   window.focus();
   window.print();
   window.close();
 }
```

Google Chrome can get it and just print it in a PDF file, but IE can't do anything. I have read about `document.close` but it works only with ID.

Don't know, should I try another way? I did button for jsPDF but it's officially bad for css styling.